# Spring boot, writing native query with parameters

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In short we have little bit complex query that also uses a function crosstab from postgresql.

We are trying to add this query to spring boot and jpa repositories and adding some parametere like id. So it is something like a dynamic query with id parametrized.

Here is query

```
enter code h--create extension if not exists tablefunc -> samo jedno za bazu
select *
from crosstab(
'SELECT 
    sd.entry_id,        
    a."name" ,
    coalesce (sd.value_string , cast(sd.value_decimal as varchar(38)) ,cast(sd.value_timestamp as varchar(50)) ) value_n
FROM 
    dataset d
    inner join attribute a 
        on d.dataset_id = a.dataset_id
    inner join attribute_value sd
        on a.attribute_id = sd.attribute_id
where 
    d.dataset_id = ?1 -> PARAMETER HERE
order by 1 ',
'SELECT distinct        
    a."name" 
FROM 
    dataset d
    inner join attribute a 
        on d.dataset_id = a.dataset_id
    inner join attribute_value sd
        on a.attribute_id = sd.attribute_id
where 
    d.dataset_id = ?1 -> PARAMETER HERE
order by 1 '
) as ct (entry_id int, "Buyer Name" varchar(255), "Car Model" varchar(50), "Price"    decimal(38,10), "Sale Date" timestamp )";
```

The problem is when we try to put this into Jpa interface and Query annotation. This id does not get inserted into this string, this ?1 does not get replaced with id parameter.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,value = """
        
        select *
        from crosstab(
            'SELECT\s
                sd.entry_id,
                a."name",
                coalesce (sd.value_string , cast(sd.value_decimal as varchar(38)) ,  cast(sd.value_timestamp as varchar(50)) ) value_n
            FROM\s
                dataset d
                inner join attribute a\s
                    on d.dataset_id = a.dataset_id
                inner join attribute_value sd
                    on a.attribute_id = sd.attribute_id
            where\s
                d.dataset_id = ?1
            order by 1 ',
            'SELECT distinct
                a."name"
            FROM
                dataset d
                inner join attribute a\s
                    on d.dataset_id = a.dataset_id
                inner join attribute_value sd
                    on a.attribute_id = sd.attribute_id
            where\s
                d.dataset_id = ?1
            order by 1 '
        ) as ct (entry_id int, "Buyer Name" varchar(255), "Car Model" varchar(50), "Price" decimal(38,10), "Sale Date" timestamp );            
        
        """)
List<Map<String,Object>> constructTableFromDatasetAttributeValue(@Param("id") Long id);
```

Comment: Try to use `:id` (since you declare `@Param("id")`) instead of `?1`

Comment: Same issue, I'm trying to pass the `id` in different ways (`:id`, `?1`, `$1`), But these didn't help

Comment: I ended building query on my own. My query was very complex so it made sense for me to build it from scratch